# SPQuery calculated fields filter does not work in SharePoint 2007/2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, spquery, spsitedataquery

I have a calculated field in my list and I am trying to use filter on this field. For some reason, the following query always returns all items instead of a filtered item collection:

```
var spQuery = new SPQuery
    {
        Query = @"<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Score' /><Value Type='Calculated'>10000</Value></Geq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>",
        RowLimit = 200,
        ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='Username' />"
    };

var spList = web.Lists["Users"];

var spListItemCollection = spList.GetItems(spQuery);
```

Comment: I've amended the title on the basis of the tags, and assume you had this problem on both versions of SharePoint. If your difficulty was in relation to just one of them, would you re-tag and edit the title? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try using

`spQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `query` element from your SPQuery. See syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx)

Comment: I have seen this before. From what I have tested so far, calculated fields cannot be used for filtering. I tried earlier in a CQWP and could not find any way to compare on calculated fields no matter what data type they were defined as

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ViewFields section (to get all columns, also those that are needed for calculation) or set [SPQUery.IncludeMandatoryColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.includemandatorycolumns.aspx)